# Cumulative visit by hours in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am tring to compare 2 different days hour by hour, (but cumulatively)

For example comparing the total visitor count by 12 o'clock today, with yesterday. How can I find out what was the total count of visitors at a specific time ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to simply view a cumalitive graph directly in Google Analytics from a certain hour.

What you can do is specify your date range and then view by hour, count how many visitors you had each hour starting with the time you'd like to gather data from. Then stick it into excel and create a graph that way.

If this is too long winded I am sure there are apps available that will do just that, check out: http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to export the hourly data to Excel, and then pull all the data you want (Ex- The 12:00 hour from each day) together for analysis and comparison.

If someone knows a better way through the UI, I would love to hear it.